# Posting an array as part of a Schema with React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I have the following Schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  balance: [{newBalance: Number, balanceDate: Date}],
});
```

What I want to do is make a post request from my React frontend using Axios, and save the 'newBalance' as a number pulled from state and `balanceDate` as today's date.

However, I can't figure out how to access the 'newBalance' and `balanceDate`.

If I try the following, it just posts an empty array to my database:

```
  onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dayCurrent = new Date().toLocaleString();

    await axios.post("/api/submit/submitDebt", {
      newBalance: this.state.balance,
      balanceDate: dayCurrent,
    })

    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
```

And similarly, if I try the following, it errors out:

```
  onSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const dayCurrent = new Date().toLocaleString();

    await axios.post("/api/submit/submitDebt", {
      balance.newBalance: this.state.balance,
      balance.balanceDate: dayCurrent,
    })

    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
```

So how do I access my Schema's `newBalance` and `balanceDate`, and append new entries rather than replace the original ones?

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: what error you get by the first approach?

Comment: Sorry - it's not erroring out.. It's just not posting the data to the database. It posts an empty array, without either 'newBalance' or 'balanceDate' in it.